# Show items in a box after clicking one by one using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have written a code, where it will show the next 12 months from current month. Suppose, now is Oct 2015, so it will show all next 12 months, that is upto Oct 2016. I am showing it in a list. But, I want to create a box with right-left arrow enabled. After clicking on left-right arrow it will show next item. After clicking on right arrow it will show next item and after clicking on left arrow it will show previous item. Data items will be shown in a box. Please check my below code, which will print next 12 months from current.

```js
angular.module('picker', []).controller('pickercontroller', function($scope) {
    var date = new Date();
    var months = [],
        monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
    for(var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
        
        
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    $scope.months = months;
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="picker">
  <div ng-controller="pickercontroller">
    <li ng-repeat="currMonth in months">{{currMonth}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, check my fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/abhijitloco/cqbqow2L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code to see how you can change the selected month via ng-click

https://jsfiddle.net/jddg3som/

**Controller**

```
angular.module('picker', []).controller('pickerCtrl', function($scope) {
  var date = new Date();
  var months = [],
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  }

  $scope.changeMonth = function(steps) {
    if ($scope.monthIndex + steps >= 0 &&
      $scope.monthIndex + steps <= 11
    ) {
      $scope.monthIndex = $scope.monthIndex + steps;
      $scope.monthName = $scope.months[$scope.monthIndex];
    }

  };

  $scope.monthIndex = 0;
  $scope.months = months;
  $scope.monthName = months[0];

});
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app="picker">
  <div ng-controller="pickerCtrl">
    <h1>   {{monthName}} </h1>
    <button ng-click="changeMonth(1);">Next Month</button>
    <button ng-click="changeMonth(-1);">Previous Month</button>
    <li ng-repeat="currMonth in months">{{currMonth}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After, Jul 2016, next is not working. Please take a look.

Comment: Oh i guess a year has 12 months. Good to know! Edited

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` to handle button event and for next month check whether next month is available in `months` array or not. If available then set next month from array.

Same for previous month

```js
angular.module('picker', []).controller('pickercontroller', function($scope) {
  var date = new Date();
  var months = [],
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  $scope.months = months;
  $scope.currMonth = months[0];
  $scope.nextMonth = nextMonth;
  $scope.prevMonth = prevMonth;

  function prevMonth() {
    var index = $scope.months.indexOf($scope.currMonth);
    if (index != 0 && index < $scope.months.length) {
      $scope.currMonth = $scope.months[index - 1];
    }
  }

  function nextMonth() {
    var index = $scope.months.indexOf($scope.currMonth);
    if (index < $scope.months.length - 1) {
      $scope.currMonth = $scope.months[index + 1];
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="picker">
  <div ng-controller="pickercontroller">
    <p>{{currMonth}}</p>
    <button ng-click="prevMonth()">Previous Month</button>
    <button ng-click="nextMonth()">Next Month</button>
  </div>
</div>
```